# Adb was accidentally removed. How to restore it on Mac?

Tags: adb

I have installed Android Studio 2.2 on my mac. While playing with "ln" command, i removed "adb" through incorrect arguments usage.
 How can i restore the "adb"? 
If i try to install SDK tools, it tries to stop adb, which can't be found.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/adb/info

Answer (score 0):

Download platform-tools_rXX...zip for your operations system ad extract ad
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/adb/info